# Calling Function and Store value of text complete from designer view

Tags: javascript, adapt

I have created these few functions in order to retrieve the value from the text confirmation, however its is not calling when i pressed enter? is there anyway that i can call this function

> adapt-textConfirmation.js

```
function(ComponentView, Adapt) {
var TextConfirmation = ComponentView.extend({
     events: {
        'click [type="checkbox"]': 'onConfirmation',
        'keyup .component-item input':'onKeyPress'
        //This is new Code
}


onKeyPress: function(event) {
        if (event.which !== 13) return;
        //<ENTER> keypress
        this.getDatabaselink(event);
              //This is new Method
    },

    getDatabaselink: function() {
        datalink = Adapt.course.get('_globals')._components._textConfirmation.Database
        console.log("datalink "+ datalink)
          //This is new Method
    },
```

> properties.schema

```
"Database": {
  "type": "string",
  "required": true,
  "default": "",
  "inputType": "Text",
  "validators": [],
  "help": "This is the label for Database link",
  "translatable": true
}
```